# How to correctly update sklearn in Spyder?

Tags: python, spyder

I have the following problem. I have updated sklearn using `pip install --upgrade sklearn`. I can see that my sklearn is up to date, that is version `0.23.2`.

[image: CMD]

But when I check it in Spyder using:

```
import sklearn
print(sklearn.__version__)
```

I get an output of 0.19.2. My numpy and scipy are also up to date. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: This indicates that you are not running the same Python installation that you installed/upgraded sklearn to.

Answer (score 0):

seems like sypder is running on a different version of python
please try

```
pip3 install --upgrade sklearn
```

maybe base python on your system is `python2` while the one that came with anaconda is 3.8 or higher

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. If I run "python --version" in my cmd I get "Python 3.7.2" so my base python is Python3, isn`t it? I also tried "pip3 install --upgrade sklearn", but my sklearn is 0.23.2, too.

Comment: maybe you have different installs of python3, one which you installed and one which came with default anaconda install. It is not very likely but could happen. In that case try going to anaconda GUI and open `Environments` tab and selecting the environment you are working in. which in your case will be `base(root)` and install/upgrade sklearn from there. let me know if that works for you

Comment: I have reinstalled anaconda. Now it seems to be OK. Thanks for help!